# Count distinct and case issue

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've reproduced live data problem on **Snowflake** demo db.
case "Mark 1" is evaluated as NULL (it's ok). I assume that count distinct based on this condition ("Mark 2") should return 0 but it returns 1. There is no difference between count distinct and count.

What am I missing? Why in this case null are counted?

Code:

```sql
WITH _table1 as(
    SELECT 
        O_CUSTKEY,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN O_TOTALPRICE>=50000 AND O_TOTALPRICE<100000 THEN O_ORDERKEY END) AS NO_SALES_OVER_50_TO_100,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN O_TOTALPRICE>=100000 THEN O_TOTALPRICE END) AS NO_SALES_OVER_100
    FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.ORDERS
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT 
    O_CUSTKEY,
    CASE WHEN NO_SALES_OVER_50_TO_100>0 THEN O_CUSTKEY END, --Mark 1
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN NO_SALES_OVER_50_TO_100>0 THEN O_CUSTKEY end) --Mark 2
FROM _table1
WHERE O_CUSTKEY=8117
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: What does the raw data coming out of your CTE for that custkey look like?

Comment: You asking about result of SELECT * FROM _table1 WHERE O_CUSTKEY=8117?

|O_CUSTKEY                              |NO_SALES_OVER_50_TO_100|NO_SALES_OVER_100  |
|---------------------------------------|-----------------------|-------------------|
|8117                                   |0                      |4                  |

Comment: @Bart Edit your question, comments do not format well.

Comment: @Bart . . . This looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug, because if to check the cases with simple logic you get 0 for mark 2

```
WITH table1 as (
    SELECT 
        100 as column1,
        --0 as column2
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN O_TOTALPRICE>=50000 AND O_TOTALPRICE<100000 THEN O_ORDERKEY END) as column2
    FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.ORDERS
    WHERE O_CUSTKEY = 8117
    GROUP BY 1
)
select column1, column2,
    case when column2 >0 then column1 end as mark1,
    count(distinct mark1) as mark2
FROM table1
WHERE column1 = 100
group by 1,2;
```

gives

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 MARK1   MARK2
100     0       NULL    1
```

were

```
WITH table1 as (
    SELECT 
        100 as column1,
        0 as column2
        --COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN O_TOTALPRICE>=50000 AND O_TOTALPRICE<100000 THEN O_ORDERKEY END) as column2
    FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.ORDERS
    WHERE O_CUSTKEY = 8117
    GROUP BY 1
)
select column1, column2,
    case when column2 >0 then column1 end as mark1,
    count(distinct mark1) as mark2
FROM table1
WHERE column1 = 100
group by 1,2;
```

gives

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 MARK1   MARK2
100     0       NULL    0
```

Thus you should post it to snowflake as the bug it is.

Comment: Ok. I'll try :) Thanks